# getting exec-maven-plugin to execute a class in a dependency

Tags: maven

I have two individual maven projects named Utilities and Campaigns. My utilities project has dependencies in it. The Campaigns project needs to execute the main method inside a class within Utilities. To accomplish this, I have been using the exec-maven-plugin. Using this plugin, I'm able to execute the main method of the dependency (Utilities) from my Campaigns pom file. However, transitive dependencies from Utilities don't seem to resolve when I execute the method. I can get around this by adding the same dependencies to both pom files, but if possible I'd like to avoid this redundancy and just inherit from Utilities. I've included the plugin portion of my Campaign pom file below. This is a little confusing, but is there a way I can get around this without having to define the same dependencies? Without having to list the dependencies in the plugin section?

The main method is found in com.sample.generics.Login.java.

Campaign.pom

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.sample.generics.Login</mainClass>
                    <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>${resourcesDir}</argument>
                        <argument>${settingsFile}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <includeProjectDependencies>true</includeProjectDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider also creating an executable jar in your Utilities project.See something like https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven.
This executable jar could then contain all the dependencies you have.
(ensure that it exists next to your regular jar with a different classifier, for example)
You could then execute that in your exec-maven.

Alternatively, in your Utilities build, you could copy all your Utilities dependencies to a separate directory, (e.g. /target/deps) (see maven dependency plugin for that, https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) , and add that directory to the classpath of exec maven